# Toggling classes of individual li elements by click in a v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

After over an hour trying unsuccessfully to implement [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737502/871404) into my app I decided to ask help here. My `li` items' class won't toggle and I can't figure out why. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<li :class="classObject(event)" v-for="event in events" @click="showEvent(event)">
  ...
</li>
```

JS:

```
methods: {
  classObject(event) {
    return {
      active: event.active,
      'event': true
    };
  },
  showEvent: function(event) {
    event.active = !event.active;
  }
},
mounted() {
  axios.get(this.eventsJsonUrl)
    .then(response => {
      this.events = response.data;
      this.events.map((obj) => {
        obj.active = false;
        return obj;
      })
    })
}
```

Note that my `events` array of object doesn't initially have an active property, I'm adding it in `mounted` hook.

Just in case here's a `console.log` of the resulting `events` array:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the class dependent on the variable like this:

```
<li class="event" :class="{ active: event.active }" v-for="event in events" @click="showEvent(event)">
  ...
</li>
```

Where the function `showEvent` toggles the event.active variable like you already have.

EDIT: see this jsfiddle to see that this works: https://jsfiddle.net/84zhx1et/

EDIT 2: I see what is going wrong in your example now: You are trying to dynamically add the active property to the events, but VueJs won't trigger this change. You can set the property like this to make sure VueJs re-renders the events:

```
  this.events.map((obj) => {
    this.$set(obj, 'active', false)
  })
```

See this JsFiddle which uses this method: https://jsfiddle.net/84zhx1et/1/

Comment: Doesn't work. And in theory my code already make the class dependent on the `event.active` value.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Can you print your example where you tried this and it doesn't work? Works perfectly fine in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84zhx1et/

Comment: @drake035 See my updated answer to see the solution for what I think is going wrong in your scenario

Comment: Thanks, you're my man! I didn't know Vue cannot detect property additions, now I do (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)